# FastApi - receiving payload from php array

Tags: python, php, fastapi

I'm getting the error below on an FastAPI app. The error is related to the payload coming from a PHP array. I'm fine changing the input_data to another type, my challenge is the the input does look like a regular dict, so I don't know how allow read this array as a dict.

```
async def post(input_data:dict):

{#908
  +"detail": array:1 [
    0 => {#890
  +"type": "dict_type"
  +"loc": array:1 [
    0 => "body"
  ]
  +"msg": "Input should be a valid dictionary"
  +"input": "{"test":"No","fields":"X"}"
  +"url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/dict_type"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expecting to read the dict that is contained in the array.

Comment: What does the request sent on the wire look like? Are you sending the return value from `json_encode` as serialized as a string, or what does your raw data actually look like? What does your PHP code that sends the request look like?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The input_data is coming in as a string `"{"test":"No","fields":"X"}"`

You can use `Pydantic` to convert it to a dictionary.

```
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator


class InputData(BaseModel):
     input_data: dict

    @field_validator("input_data", mode='before')
    def sanitize_dict(cls, v):
        return json.loads(v)
```

then in your API route

````
async def post(input_data:InputData):
   ```Your endpoint implementation here...```
````